# Is there a command line parameter for inetmgr.exe or inetmgr6.exe to specify the remote computer name?

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, command-line-interface, iis

I want to run something like the following and immediately connect to that server.

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr6.exe \servername

or

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe \servername

Answer (score 2):

`inetmgr.exe /h` shows 2 parameters:

- `/reset` which gives no indication of what is being reset bu is described above
- `/mmc` which opens in an MMC window. The only difference I could see was the icon for the window. Otherwise it looked the same.

It would be nice if it could take a local URL or Path and open with that location as the default, but doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: `reset` is used to reset the information in administration.config, where IIS Manager settings are stored. It can resolve many crash issues, if that config file is corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. inetmgr.exe, on a Win2k3 system, is only 22 Kb, I think it just serves as a launcher for iis.msc, which (AFAIK) is just an XML config file for the MMC. Running strings.exe on either of those files doesn't show anything that looks like command-line instructions for giving arguments.

Some quick googling didn't turn up anything for me, either.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not such command line. As the previous Answer mentioned in IIS 6 it was just a launcher for MMC.exe
in IIS 7 and above it does launches the new IIS Manager. The only command line supported is /reset that resets the preferences (like Column Widths in lists, Sorting, Size and position of Window, Remote connections settings, Assemblies downloaded for Remote Manager, etc).