# IIS10 missing components

Tags: iis, iis-10, window-server-2019

I was installing IIS components to host laravel in Windows Server 2022. After installing all the necessary components from Server Manager, I found out that those components were not found in IIS10. Anyone that encounter this issue before?

*I've tried to restart the server several times which still not able to solve this issue.

[IIS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhDdE.png)

Comment: It's more reliable to detect which components were installed via registry keys, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/discover-installed-components You might try to reset IIS Manager itself by using `/reset` https://serverfault.com/questions/154091/is-there-a-command-line-parameter-for-inetmgr-exe-or-inetmgr6-exe-to-specify-the

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PowerShell to install the missing components. This installs all the missing components within the IIS role

```
Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "Web-*" -and $_.InstallState -ne "Installed" } | Install-WindowsFeature
```

This script retrieves all features related to IIS using Get-WindowsFeature, filters out the already installed ones, and then installs the remaining features using Install-WindowsFeature. Make sure to run this script with administrator privileges.